# Adding ivars to a Category with objc_setAssociatedObject

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-category, associated-object

I'm planning to add to `iVars` to a category with `objc_setAssociatedObject()`. However, I'm unsure on when to call `objc_removeAssociatedObjects()` to get rid of them.

Is there a way the category can know when the object using it has been `de-allocated` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set an association with

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &key, otherObject, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
// or OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC
```

then `otherObject` is automatically released when `self` is deallocated. (At least if you use ARC, but I think this is also correct with manual reference counting.)

So you don't have to call `objc_removeAssociatedObjects()` explicitly, unless you want to get
rid of the added objects before the main object is deallocated.